# Handling table tag using selenium webdriver

Tags: html, selenium

I am trying to find the element from the table using selenium web driver, but since the table id's are dynamic i am not able to click on the one which i want.

For example in a table:

```
       col_1 entity_id      .    . . . .   col_10  
row1     1                                  Edit(Button) delete (button)
row2     2                                  Edit(Button) delete (button)
```

So here if I want to click the edit button of the particular (`entity_id`) lets say 1, I cannot see any relation between them. Is there any way?

Below are the HTML tags:

```
<tr id="tableRow_0" class="even" bgcolor="#e3e3e3">
<td>20003601</td>
<td>AAB Securities Finance - Amsterdam</td>
<td>EQDF</td>
<td>ShortSelling</td>
<td>Y</td>
<td>Y</td>
<td>09-09-2014</td>
<td></td>
<td>TestUser</td>
<td>09-09-2014 17:42:40</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td id="operationCol" width="110" align="center">
<input id="delete_4827" class="hrefButton buttonClass" type="button" onclick="deleteEntityReferenceList(4827)" value="Delete">
<input id="edit_4827" class="hrefButton buttonClass" type="button" onclick="updateEntityReferenceList(4827)" value="Edit">
</td>
<td align="center"> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Here i want to click on the EDIT button for id= 20001304  whose id is = edit_4831 which is dynamic. How can i associate them ?

Comment: you could use xpath to select the edit button based on a condition (your id). can you provide a proper html please.

Answer (score 0):

For your example xpath will be like this:

```
//tr[td[text()='20001304']]/td/input[@value='Edit']
```

You can use some variable instead of 20001304 for different values.

Generally, to identify the number of some column/row according to cell's content, use xpath axes (http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_axes.asp)

Comment: No i cannot use the variable too, since there is no relation between the xpath of the (Edit) button with the remaining fields like ID=20001304.

Comment: There is a relation at least because the button and the entity id are in the same row. You can identify row, which contains some entity id, and then take the button from this row.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the .NET version of WebDriver, you could use the TableDriver extension (https://github.com/jkindwall/TableDriver.NET).  It is specifically designed to handle problems like this.   Its a little hard to interpret the example table in the original question, and the html code is incomplete, but assuming the table has headers for each column, and we assume the header text for the relevant columns are "Entity Id" and "Operation", the following should accomplish the desired results.

```
Table table = Table.Create(driver.FindElement(By.Id("theTableId")));
TableCell cell = table.FindCell("Entity Id=1", "Operation");
cell.Element.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[value=Edit]")).Click();
```

**Update**

TableDriver.Java is now available.  Details here: https://github.com/jkindwall/TableDriver.Java